# How to put a div hover an other in css : specific scenario

Tags: html, css

I would like to fix a tricky problem. I have 2 `div` (a, b) on fixed position. Inside one of them (a), I have a `div` (b) in absolute position. I would like to put blue divs over the yellow one.

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k42wu2g3/3/

```css
.left {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: green;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.right {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 69%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
  left: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}
.hover {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
  <div class="hover">
    DIV HOVER RIGHT
  </div>
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT 
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT 
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT 
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT 
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
  <div class="hover">
    DIV HOVER RIGHT
  </div>
  LEFT
  CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
</div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  RIGHT
</div>
```

Comment: Your blue div is nested in the green div. Is that on purpose? If not then nesting the blue div in the yellow div would help.

Comment: yes but i cant, the blue div has to be in green div

Comment: The source of your issue essentially boils down to the `overflow` property rule declared on `.left`. So my question is; to what extent can you edit or update the html structure?

Comment: i can edit the html structure

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for? Or you need position absolute for blue div?

```css
.left {
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:30%;
  z-index:2;
  background:green;
  left:0;
  height:300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.right {
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:69%;
  z-index:1;
  background:yellow;
  left:30%;
  height:300px;
}
.hover {
  background: blue;
  position:fixed;
  left: 30%;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 5;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT 
<div class="hover">
DIV HOVER RIGHT
</div>
LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT

</div>
<div class="right">
RIGHT
</div>
```

Comment: no because the blue div has to be absolute (in my code, i have several blue div in the green div so i cant use fixed position)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Remove the blue div on hover from the green side to the yellow side?

- You havn't made clear when do you want the blue divs to move to the yellow side. Whether you want them moved on hover of the green side, or on hovering the blue divs themselves or on hovering the yellow side.
- Since you're using absolute positioning for hovers, if you do change their position from green to yellow side they will just overlap when their position changes as shown in the below code. So are you looking for that as well? Please, make your query clear.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hover').hover(function() {
    var element = $(this).detach();
    $('.right').append(element);
  });

});
```

```css
.left {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: green;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.right {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 69%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
  left: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

.hover {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
  <div class="hover">
    HOVER RIGHT 1
  </div>
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENTLEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
  <div class="hover">
    HOVER RIGHT 2
  </div>
  LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT LEFT CONTENT
</div>
<div class="right">
  RIGHT
</div>
```

Comment: no actually, it's only a css pb, i just want to display the blue divs over the right but without trigger, only in css

Comment: If you are nesting the divs inside say Parent1 div and then on hovering you want it to be shown inside another div, say Parent2. If you want to do this, using only CSS. The only option is to use position:fixed to make it look like that (since absolute positioning works with reference to its parent div tag), otherwise javascript is needed to actually move that div from one side to another.